# Grunt connect serve statics files outside root

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm having problems to configure my grunt file to add refs (css & js) to my index.html

here's my project structure:

```
src/
  demo/
    index.html
  app.js
bower_components/
  angular/
    angular.js
```

index.html:

```
<script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../app.js"></script>
```

gruntFile:

```
connect: {
  demo: {
    options: {
      port: 9000,
      hostname: 'localhost',
      open: true,
      base: 'src/demo'
    },
    livereload: {
      options: {
        middleware: function(connect) {
          return [
            connect().use(
              '/bower_components',
              connect.static('./bower_components')
            )
          ];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know why, but index.html cannot find app.js or angular.js.

Answer (score 0):

Some observations:

- the web root is `src/demo`;
- so `/index.html` maps to `src/demo/index.html`;
- therefore, `../app.js` from within `index.html` doesn't make sense, because the you can't go "up" from the web root;
- `./bower_components/...` tries to find the `bower_components` directory in `src/demo/` because it's a relative path, it should be `/bower_components/...`